# HBox child not shrinking

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a `BorderPane` as a root element, an `HBox` in it's top. In the `HBox` I have 5 `AnchorPane`s, where the 4. acts as a spacer. This is the stripped down FXML:

```
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="710.0" prefWidth="1190.0" stylesheets="@style.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <top>
      <HBox prefHeight="70.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               ...
            </AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               ...
            </AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               ...
            </AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane id="empty" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="0.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="70.0">
               ...
            </AnchorPane>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

My problem is that the `empty` pane is growing when I resize the window, but it doesn't shrink below the initial width (the size it had when the app launched).

A video to show what is (or isn't) happening: https://jumpshare.com/v/0QriIiITUlSRgLMy4ev5

Is this the expected behavior or it's a bug in JavaFX?

Comment: It shall work as expected.

 What happens when you are resizing the window to be smaller? Which parts are resizing?

Comment: When I resize it to be bigger the `empty` pane is resizing to fill the gap, but when I resize it to be smaller, nothing is resized in the hbox and the end of it will be hidden. Check this video: https://jumpshare.com/v/0QriIiITUlSRgLMy4ev5

Comment: What you have posted is correct. Please post the full code to make us able to help, because the layout is affected ny something else I guess.

Comment: Here is a basic code (full, working example) with the same behavior: http://pastebin.com/dEkCiCDu so it's not something else.

Comment: Added an aswer, I have tried it also. At me it is working properly now (the green area grows and shrinks as expected)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the FXML, in the definition of the `BorderPane` replace:

```
minWidth="-Infinity"
```

with

```
minWidth="0".
```

The problem was that your `HBox` was not shrinking, because the `BorderPane` itself was not shrinking anymore.

Minimal width of 0 will ensure, that the `BorderPane` will shrink, and therefore the `HBox` will be also resized.

I have tried your FXML, with this small modification the layout seems correct.